# Fetching email using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, pop3

I need to fetch email from my  gmail account using RoR.

```
require 'net/pop'
Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, username, password) do |pop|  
    if pop.mails.empty?  
        puts 'No mail.'  
    else  
        #pop.each_mail do |mail|  
            #p mail.header  
            #p mail.pop
            puts "Mails present"
        #end  
     end  
 end
```

I get a timeout error.

```
usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60:in `new': execution expired
    (Timeout::Error)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:206:in `old_open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:206:in `old_open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/pop.rb:438:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/pop.rb:432:in `start'
    from script/mail.rb:4
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Your account accept POP connection ?

Comment: Can you connect to the pop-host from the command-line? `telnet pop.gmail.com pop` or `telnet pop.gmail.com 110`. If that doesn't work, your problem is not related to RoR.

Comment: telnet pop.gmail.com 995
Trying 74.125.127.109...
Connected to pop.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

So,it does connect via telnet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use SSL

Answer (score 17):

Try this one:

```
require 'net/pop'
Net::POP3.enable_ssl(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)  
Net::POP3.start('pop.gmail.com', 995, username, password) do |pop|  
  if pop.mails.empty?  
    puts 'No mails.'  
  else  
    pop.each_mail do |mail|  
      p mail.header  
      p mail.pop  
    end  
  end  
end
```