# Receiving emails in Ruby

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

I'm working with actionmailer. I'm trying to send a mail from `email_idA` to `email_idB`, then fetch that email from `email_idB`, and do some string operations on it to look for specific keywords.

I understood how to send the email. But how do I receive that email from `email_idB`'s inbox? What configurations do I need to do? And how do I extract the email body as plain text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean fetch or receive ? Your question uses both these terms and not sure what you mean.

1. If you just want to do a keyword search on the mails you sent, why not store the outgoing mail in DB and do the search ? (as you said "somehow fetch that email")
2. To be able to receive emails in your rails app, you would need to implement the `receive` method in your mailer. Follow this link - [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#receiving-emails)
3. If you meant fetching emails from your inbox then you have to use POP3. Follow this SO answer - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666798/fetching-email-using-ruby-on-rails)

Im not sure whats your requirement but I'm sure you will find the above links useful :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Point 3 is basically what I want to do.
If I wanted to forward the emails from my gmail to the Rails app, how would I do that?

Comment: Point 2 will help in that case. As mentioned you need to implement a `receive` method in the mailer.